# filesize() returning false in php

Tags: php

i'm trying to make a jason of the files and there size,
its working perfectly for the directory that this php file is saved in but when i change the directory the filesize() returns false.
this works fine:

```
<?php
  header('Content-Type: application/json');
  $dir= "./"; //path
  $list = array(); //main array

if(is_dir($dir)){
   if($dh = opendir($dir)){
       while(($file = readdir($dh)) != false){

           if($file == "." or $file == ".."){
               //...
           } else { //create object with two fields
               $list3 = array(
               'file' => $file, 
               'size' => filesize($file));
               array_push($list, $list3);
           }
       }
   }

   $return_array = array('files'=> $list);
   echo json_encode($return_array);
}
?>
```

but this doesn't work:

```
<?php
 header('Content-Type: application/json');
  $dir= "Syllabus/Undergraduate Courses/BCA/Semester 1"; //path
  $list = array(); //main array

if(is_dir($dir)){
   if($dh = opendir($dir)){
       while(($file = readdir($dh)) != false){

           if($file == "." or $file == ".."){
               //...
           } else { //create object with two fields
               $list3 = array(
               'file' => $file, 
               'size' => filesize($file));
               array_push($list, $list3);
           }
       }
   }

   $return_array = array('files'=> $list);
   echo json_encode($return_array);
}
?>
```

error message:

**Warning**:  filesize(): stat failed for Communicat_GeneralEnglish1stSemsterCopyCopy2Copy.pdf in **C:\xampp\htdocs\college\listFiles.php** on line **17**

**Warning**:  filesize(): stat failed for Environmental Studies_AECC-Environment-Studies-BCA.pdf in **C:\xampp\htdocs\college\listFiles.php** on line **17**

**Warning**:  filesize(): stat failed for Foundation Course On Computers_B.CA_.pdf in **C:\xampp\htdocs\college\listFiles.php** on line **17**

**Warning**:  filesize(): stat failed for Fundamentals Of Mathematics_B.CA_.3.pdf in **C:\xampp\htdocs\college\listFiles.php** on line **17**

**Warning**:  filesize(): stat failed for Problem Solving And Programming With C_B.CA_.2.pdf in **C:\xampp\htdocs\college\listFiles.php** on line **17**
{"files":[{"file":"Communicat_GeneralEnglish1stSemsterCopyCopy2Copy.pdf","size":"0 bytes"},{"file":"Environmental Studies_AECC-Environment-Studies-BCA.pdf","size":"0 bytes"},{"file":"Foundation Course On Computers_B.CA_.pdf","size":"0 bytes"},{"file":"Fundamentals Of Mathematics_B.CA_.3.pdf","size":"0 bytes"},{"file":"Problem Solving And Programming With C_B.CA_.2.pdf","size":"0 bytes"}]}

Comment: Check your error logs, on error filesize should emit a warning.

Comment: Added the error message

Comment: `readdir` gives you the file names, without the path. `filesize` probably needs the file name along with the relative or absolute path. e.g. `filesize($dir . '/' . $file))` or similar.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! it worked